# Creating heatmap and serving it

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, gis, geospatial, heatmap

I am using Google Maps V3 API to plot markers on a map. I have some point data (containing `lat`, `lng`, `value`) that I want to use to create heatmaps and overlay them on the Google Map.

**Problem:** The heatmap does not change often, probably updates once every 3 months. Will the better method of delivering the heatmap to Google Maps be to convert the data points into a heatmap, generate several (5-9) different zoom version of it, and serve it via a standalone tile server?

If so, how can this conversion to heatmaps, generating different versions be done, and which tile server will be a good interface for the generated tiles and to feed to Google Maps API?

Alternatively, would it be better to generate an array of points (regular N by N grid pattern) with the calculated heatmap values for each point, then generate the heatmap on top of Google Maps using one of those HTML5 + JS plugins? I am concerned about users' browsers not being able to support HTML5 canvas.

Comment: Have you looked at Fusion Table heatmaps? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#FusionTablesHeatmaps. Not sure if you can weight them by the value though.

Comment: I think your question is a better fit on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/); it is more about design options than a specific coding problem, which is why I don't think you are having much response activity here. Maybe consider touching base with a Moderator and see about migrating the question?